# Ambiguous base class conversion with a compressed pair

Tags: c++, c++11

So I tried creating a compressed pair using the [empty base optimization](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Empty_Base_Optimization). I would like it such that if class `a` and `b` are empty then `compressed_pair<a, b>` is empty as well. So I defined my compressed pair something like this:

```
template <class First, class Second>
struct compressed_pair : First, Second 
{
    compressed_pair() {}
    compressed_pair(const First& x, const Second & y)
    : First(x), Second(y) 
    {}
    First& first()  { return *this; }
    Second& second() { return *this; }
};
```

However, if one of the types inherit from the other it becomes ambiguous. For example, when I compile this program:

```
struct a
{};

struct b : a
{};

int main()
{
    compressed_pair<a, b> p;
    auto x = p.first();
}
```

I get this error from clang:

```
compressed_pair.cpp:8:30: error: ambiguous conversion from derived class 'compressed_pair<a, b>' to base class 'a':
    struct compressed_pair<struct a, struct b> -> struct a
    struct compressed_pair<struct a, struct b> -> struct b -> struct a
    First& first()  { return *this; }
                             ^~~~~
compressed_pair.cpp:21:16: note: in instantiation of member function 'compressed_pair<a, b>::first' requested here
    auto x = p.first();
               ^
```

So how can I avoid the ambiguous conversion and still have `compressed_pair<a, b>` be empty?

Comment: This is a very error-prone method of implementing a `compressed_pair`, you should probably use SFINAE and `is_empty` (and possibly other) traits to inherit from `First` or `Second` based on which one is empty. Edit: Here's the [`boost::compressed_pair`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/detail/compressed_pair.hpp) header, they delegate to several different specializations of `compressed_pair_imp` based on traits of the first and second types.

Comment: @Praetorian at least `is_final` too.

Comment: Interestingly enough, `boost::compressed_pair` [also breaks on this](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/32f150c4d3532a9f). In any event, I'm not convinced that it's possible to get `sizeof(compressed_pair<a,b>)` below 2, since there are two distinct `a` subobjects here and they need to have distinct addresses.

Comment: @Praetorian Yes SFINAE is needed. I just simplified the example.

Comment: @T.C. I don't need each object to have a separate address. I am trying to optimize for emptiness, so that `std::is_empty<compressed_pair<a,b>>()` is true. And it is possible, except for corner cases, like what I've shown.

Comment: Then simply enforce a constraint that a First is not implicitly convertible to Second (e.g. using is_convertible in C++11).   This has an effect of not allowing your template to be instantiated in your "corner cases".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem that you have is that from `compressed_pair` there are two bases to which the conversion can apply. You need to be able to drive the compiler into selecting one of them. The first thing that comes to mind is to add another layer of inheritance that you can use as a selector:

```
template <int N, typename T>
struct element : T {};

template <typename T, typename U>
struct compressed_pair : element<0, T>, element<1, U> { ... };
```

Then your implementation for the accessors could be:

```
template <typename T, typename U>
T& compressed_pair<T,U>::first() {
    return static_cast<element<0,T>&>(*this);
}
```

The cast inside the accessor forces the selection of one of the two direct bases, `element<0,T>`.  From that point onwards, there is only one base of type `T`.

You can also use move the accessor to that intermediate step, rather than have it in the complete type. Finally, through specialization you should be able to provide a different implementation for `element` that supports non-class types as your current implementation will choke on types like `int`.

Answer (score 0):

Use `virtual` inheritance to avoid ambiguity or require that `First` and `Second` do not derived from each other.   It's an either/or decision.   You need to decide whether avoiding ambiguity or allowing the empty base optimisation is more important to you.

Generally speaking, to avoid ambiguity, the one that is inherited more than once (i.e. by both your `compressed_pair` and the other struct type) needs to be a virtual base.   Since the template might be instantiated using anything, this means that both `First` and `Second` must be a virtual base of `compressed_pair`, and `a` must be a `virtual` base of `b`.

If you always know that `Second` might be derived from `First` but `First` will never be derived from `Second` you can relax this somewhat (with the cost of ambiguity again, if `First` is derived from `Second`).

Bear in mind that virtual inheritance does impose some constraints on how the classes work.  For example, it affects order of construction of bases, requires any subsequently derived classes to manage construction of virtual bases inherited via base classes, etc.

Comment: The whole point of using a compressed pair is to save space on empty classes. The virtual inheritance overhead completely defeats the purpose.

Comment: ... and you do not want to share the base, you want an object holding an `a` object and an unrelated `b` object, whose base may have a different value than the first element in the pair.